# Hello How to get the middle letter of acronym to be small?

Tags: acronyms

I am defining the acronym

```
\acro{IoT}{Internet of Things}
```

when I call it in short form I use `\acs{IoT}`, however in the PDF file it shows IOT.

How I can get the letter "o" to appear in the PDF file in a small letter case

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe define it as `\textsc{IoT}` to get small-caps?

Comment: I’m not sure if that’s exactly what you want, though. The `fontspec` package also defines a caps-to-small-caps mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, It did not work

Comment: I’m not clear exactly what output you want.

Comment: to have in the list of abbreviations the following: IoT    Internet of Things  not IOT    Internet of Things Also in the text to have (IoT) not (IOT)

Comment: I got IoT when I tried `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{iot}{
  short = IoT ,
  long  = Internet of Things,
  class = maybelongonly,
}
\begin{document}
\acs{iot}
\end{document}`. What code/packages are you using?

Comment: You need to show a minimal working example

Comment: Thank you very much! much appreciated!!